# Analogy of Arrays and Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Let me ask a very short question:

I have an array of characters (let's say lowercase only), where I want each character to become the very next of the alphabet. Consider that 'z' becomes 'a'. I would use:

```
while (s[i] != '\0')
{
    if (s[i] == 'z')
        s[i] = 'a');
    else
        s[i] += 1;
    i++;
}
```

Right? Now, if I had to work with pointers, would I say instead:

```
while (*s != '\0')
{
    if (*s == 'z')
        *s = 'a');
    else
        *s += 1; //Don't know if this is correct...
    s++; //edited, I forgot D:
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: s++, not i++ in the loop

Comment: code review, simple mistake made by the author; no point keeping it open.

Comment: There is no question in this question.

Answer (score 1):

`*s += 1` is correct. You also need to change `i++` to `s++`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be correct:

```
while (*s != '\0')
{
    if (*s == 'z')
        *s = 'a');
    else
        *s += 1; //Don't think if this is correct... yes, it is
    s++; //small correction here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to increment `s` as pointer

```
while (*s != '\0')
{
    if (*s == 'z')
        *s = 'a';
    else
        *s += 1; //Don't think if this is correct...
    s++;
}
```

Secondly, it is about, whether you have an array you are pointing to, or dynamically allocated memory (`malloc`ed string), because you cannot change a string like

```
char *str = "Hello, World!"; // is in read-only part of memory, cannot be altered
```

whereas

```
char strarr[] = "Hello, World!"; //is allocated on stack, can be altered using a pointer
char* pstr = strarr;
*pstr = 'B'; //can be altered using a pointer -> "Bello, World!"
```

or

```
char* dynstr = malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
memset(dynstr, 0, 32);
strncpy(dynstr, "Hello, World!", 14); // remember trailing '\0'
char* pstr = dynstr;
*pstr = 'B'; // -> "Bello, World!"
```

Comment: Dynamically allocated memory is not the issue. The problem case is pointing to a string literal or to an object defined with `const`. (And note that pointing to an array initialized with a string literal is not the same as pointing to a string literal.) Otherwise, whether objects have static, automatic, or allocated storage duration is irrelevant.